# Making a working href button, how do you make the link work?

Tags: href

I tried to replace a simple url in an href button and some how messed everything up.

```
<button onclick="location.href="https://arborapaloalto.securecafe.com/onlineleasing/arbora/scheduletour.aspx">Request an appointment</button>
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you add the original HTML element and the link you would like it to be reconfigured to?

Comment: You could also just call a normal <a> link inside the button instead of an onclick event like this.

<button>
<a href="arborapaloalto.securecafe.com/onlineleasing/arbora/scheduletour.aspx"> Request an appointment</a>
</button>

Citation ->
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Answer (score 1):

You've doubled up on double quotes in the `onclick`. For the href URL, you need to switch to single quotes:

```html
<button onclick="location.href='https://arborapaloalto.securecafe.com/onlineleasing/arbora/scheduletour.aspx'">Request an appointment</button>
```

To open in a new tab:

```html
<button onclick="window.open('https://arborapaloalto.securecafe.com/onlineleasing/arbora/scheduletour.aspx', '_blank')">Request an appointment</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to make it open in a new tab- the following did not work? <button onclick="location.href='https://arborapaloalto.securecafe.com/onlineleasing/arbora/scheduletour.aspx'"target="_blank">Request an appointment</button>